# Silently installing Java 8 using Powershell

Tags: java, windows, installation

I was reading about installing the Java using MSI. I find this rather complicated. What is wrong about using the .exe and install silently like this?

> Start-Process -FilePath jre-8u25-windows-x64.exe -ArgumentList
>   "/s" -PassThru -Wait

It works in my case. Any doubts, helpful hints about this?

Answer (score 1):

calling this from dos-window:

```
jre-8u25-windows-x64.exe /s INSTALLDIR=c:\progra~1\jre /L install64.log
```

will not work (progra~1 is substitution for 'program files'). It terminates immediately without any message. Calling the same thru powershell works fine:

```
powershell start-process -filepath jre-8u25-windows-x64.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=c:\progra~1\jre,/L,install64.log"
```

Does anyone know what makes difference?